# How to check value from array and map to ngModel in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngmodel

This is my model class. I have to map the values from array to respective ngModel checking the **title** and pushing the **result** in ngModel value.

In component file

```
  export class demoModel{
          demo1:string
          demo2:string
        }



demo=new demoModel()

var data=    [{title:"demo1",result:1},{title:"demo2",result:2}]

for (const iterator of this.data) {
  console.log(iterator)
//works upto here 
for (const key of Object.keys(this.demo)) {
this.demo[key]=iterator.result;          
}
}
```

IN HTML

```
  <input [(ngModel)]="demo1">
  <input [(ngModel)]="demo2">
```

How to achieve this in angular?

I tried using Object.keys to map the values but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mapping the data and the object's key , if **data.title** matches with the object's key , assign the **data.result** to the object's key.

```
export class demoModel {
    demo1: string = '';
    demo2: string = '';
}

demo = new demoModel();

var data = [{
    title: "demo1",
    result: 1
}, {
    title: "demo2",
    result: 2
}]


this.data.map(x => {
    Object.keys(this.demo).map(y => {
        if (y == x.title) {
            this.demo[y] = x.result;

        }
    })
})`
```